# scipy.stats.uniform.expect have a different value than manual calculation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

This is most likely because I do not know how to use the standard scipy expect function method. When I use:

```
  from scipy.stats import uniform
  uniform.expect(lambda k: k**2,lb=-0.2,ub=0.2)
```

I got value :  0.0026666666666666666

If I use manual calculation:

```
  np.mean(np.random.uniform(-0.2,0.2,1000)**2)
```

I got 0.013235491320680141, which is the right value I expect. So what did I do wrong with standard expect or integral function? Any help please.

Comment: Documentation for [`scipy.stats.rv_continuous.expect` is here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.expect.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.expect)

Comment: I checked but still do not know how to get the right value. there is no example in the documentation.

Comment: Your understanding of `ub` and `lb` is incorrect. They are not parameters for the uniform distribution, because `expect` is not just a method of that distribution. `dist.expect(f, lb, ub)` means _"expected value of `f(x)` where `x ~ dist` such that `lb < x < ub`"_

Comment: this is actually how I understand as uniform.expect(lambda k: k**2,lb=-0.2,ub=0.2) , but the result is not correct.

Comment: What you wrote means `x ~ Uniform[0, 1], find E[x^2] given x < 0.2`. `lb` and `ub` **do not parameterize the distribution**. That's what `loc` and `scale` are for

Comment: I got it. Thank you! so what is "lb" actually means? somewhat confusing to me.

Comment: What you wrote is equivalent to `uniform.expect(lambda k: k**2 if -0.2 < k < 0.2 else 0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation for `expect`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.expect.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.expect), `ub` and `lb` do not mean what you think they do. They are bounds on the integral, not parameters for the distribution.

You actually want:

```
scipy.stats.uniform(loc=-0.2, scale=0.4).expect(lambda x: x**2)
```